# Corona 'ApplicationResume' Event Not Working On iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, coronasdk

'applicationStart' is working, but 'applicationResume' doesn't work, I already set "UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend = false". 
Also it is strange that it actually works on Corona Simulator, but not work on real device (iPhone5/iOS6).

Here is the code:

```
local onSystem = function( event )
if event.type == "applicationStart" then
    system.cancelNotification()
     native.setProperty( "applicationIconBadgeNumber",0)
elseif event.type == "applicationExit" then
    print("exit")
elseif event.type == "applicationSuspend" then
    print("suspend")
elseif event.type == "applicationResume" then
    native.showAlert( "Hihi", "", { "OK" } )
end
end

-- setup a system event listener
Runtime:addEventListener( "system", onSystem )
```

Any ideas??

I found another event handler codes:

```
local function onSystemEvent( event ) 
if event.type == "applicationStart" then
    --fb.logout();        
     return true
end
if event.type == "applicationExit" then
    --fb.logout();
    return true
end
end
```

Comment: did you try to print something in resume scope to check if program actually goes there?
and I'm not sure but, you can also try to change applicationStart and applicationResume scopes.. Maybe corona or system acts them in the same way.

Comment: print something in resume scope? I can say it works on Corona Simulator, but not on real device.

Comment: or you can add this line in first place of the function to see if there is a problem with iphone5/iOS6:

print( event.type )

It can give a hint

Comment: How can I check output of 'print(event.type)' on real device??

Comment: In xcode simulator there is a consol segment there..

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I found another event handler codes (the program was not written by me), once I comment out the 'fb.logout();', it works, I checked the console, this code crash something, but I don't understand why there are two section of codes to handle system events, what is the difference between this one and the above one??  Sorry, I am new to Corona.

Comment: you can combine them, it wont be a problem.

Comment: So they are actually doing the same thing??

Comment: they are called at same time, synchronously. So, no need to call them together. You can just add fb.logout() part to onSystem function